# How do you write data in a specific cell in an excel file without overwriting data (using pandas)?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I have an excel file with column names of "Symbol", "Name", "Industry" etc.
I want someone to be able to add a stock symbol under the "symbol" column on the row with an empty cell. I do not want my program to overwrite the data in the excel file. I don't know if I should use openpyxl or xlsxwriter. In any case my code below does not work. Is there any way I can solve this?

```
    stockSymbol = input("what stock do you want to add? ")

    with pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
        wb = load_workbook(file.xlsx)
        ws = wb.active
        ws['Symbol'][1] = stockSymbol
```

Comment: This is easy to do in openpyxl. Have you tried the tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot overwrite an excel file with XlsxWriter. However, if the whole content of the excel file ("input_file.xlsx") is only this table, you can read the old content in, add the new input and then write a new excel file ("output_file.xlsx") with the updated content:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("input_file.xslx")
with pd.ExcelWriter("output_file.xlsx", mode="w", engine="xlsxwriter") as writer:
    stockSymbol = input("what stock do you want to add? ")
    new_row = {'Symbol': stockSymbol}
    df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
    df.to_excel(writer, index = False)
```